# /dev vs /exec documentation and mishandling

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Let's start with the fact that there isn't much documentation on `/dev` vs `/exec` endpoints. If you have some valuable info I can't find, I would totally love to see it, no sarcasm.

From what I can find, dev is the current editing version, and exec is the last published version of your scripts (or an older version if you so choose).

This tells me I should be able to edit my standalone web app scripts without worrying about whether it breaks things for the users because if it isn't published, they don't see the change. Except this isn't actually the case.

Very easy to duplicate, just make a new web app, and put a `console.log("Anything you want")`, in the `doGet` function. Publish and run, and you will see your log in the console, awesome! Now go back, remove the console line, **do not publish**, and run it again. Your console output will no longer run, which it should have because you didn't publish.

So my question is, where is the documentation on how this actually should function because, with the limited info I've been able to find, it appears broken.

Comment: *Now go back, remove the console line, do not publish, and run it again. Your console output will no longer run, which it should have, because you didn't publish.* I'm not sure that's true. Provide [mcve]-actual code with index.html

Comment: function doGet() {
    console.log("Testing #1");
    console.log("Testing #2");
    console.log("Testing #3");
    }


Publish and run on exec page, you'll see a page that says "The script completed but did not return anything." Now go check your executions. You'll see all 3.

Comment out the second console line. Save, and without publishing run the exec page again and check your executions, the second line will be missing.

I'm sorry, I would have formatted this all better and more readable, but I just don't get how to put code in this comment box.

Comment: Put code in your question by [edit]ing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `exec` URL is the current published version of your Web App, whereas the `dev` URL runs the most recently saved code and can only be accessed by users who have edit access.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on Web Apps:

> Once you click **Deploy**, you'll see a new dialog with a message indicating that your project has been successfully deployed as a web app.
>
> This dialog provides two important URLs for your app:
>
> The first is labeled **Current web app URL** and ends in `/exec`. This URL is for the published version of your app, based on the last version you saved and deployed.
>
> The second is the link labeled **latest code** and ends in `/dev`. This URL can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved code — not necessarily a formal version — and is intended for quick testing during development.
>
> You can share the web app URL with those you would like to use your app, provided you have granted them access.

#### Be Aware:

The ID of the web app URL for `/exec` and `/dev` endpoints are ***not*** the same.

You can see this by viewing the Web App deloyment modal -  the URL provided in the `Current web app URL` section is the `/exec` URL and the link provided in the `Test web app for your latest code.` string is the `/dev` URL. Note the IDs before the final `/` are not equivalent.

#### Reference:

- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)

Comment: "The ID of the web app URL for /exec and /dev endpoints are not the same." -- This was indeed my issue. I had sent out the wrong link and never even noticed. Thank you. And I also apologize for my sarcasm in Google's direction.