# HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL not working

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, x-frame-options

Having set the `XframeOptionMode`, the `doPost` still doesn't redirect:

```
var REDIRECT_URL = "https://stackoverflow.com";

function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("CForm.html");
  template.pubUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var html = template.evaluate();
  html.setTitle('ABCD');
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost(e){
  SendHtmlMail(e);
  return redirect().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function redirect() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>"
  );
}
```

The console error still remains

> Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyb3wh57wgW30KV8faQNqNXSDQ_zu8w3BR-_8kVwUbI/dev' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Relevant part of the HTML

```
        <form class="container" id="main_form" method="post" action="<?= pubUrl ?>">
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Business Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BusinessName" id="name" placeholder="Name of Upload" readonly>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Month and Year of Incorporation</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="MonthandYearofIncorporation">
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="Apply for Carbon"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where are you doposting from?

Comment: From a form in CForm.html

Comment: Show relevant parts of the form, especially the post part.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Why not just use `google.script.run`?

Comment: Yeah, I have simply switched to calling google script function that sends my mail and perforn other actions from my javascript. Now, I no longer get the error, but I would have loved to see the doPost work as it is supposed to.

Comment: Though, it must be noted that I now get a blank page after submitting the form through google.script.run but I am currently improvising with an alert() as redirection still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `return "<script>...</script>"` instead of using html service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though, manually pasting (hardcoding) the /exec url version of the script seems to alleviate the issue, I prefer not to.
I dropped the doPost and redirect function. Now my html now has script like:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        ... First page ...
        ... Second page ...
        <form class="container d-none" id="main_form" method="post" action="<?pubUrl?>" onsubmit="submitter(this);">
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Business Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BusinessName" id="name" placeholder="Name of Upload" readonly>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Month and Year of Incorporation</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="MonthandYearofIncorporation" required>
            </div>
            ... A very long form
            <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="Apply for Carbon"/>
        </form>
       ...
    </body>
    <script>
      //...
      function submitter(data_process){
        // Run server-side function when submitted.
        google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function(){
              //alert('Thank You!!! Your application has been received');
              window.top.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
            })
            .withFailureHandler(function(e){
              alert("Unable to submit your application. Please contact us.");
              })
            .SendHtmlMail(data_process); // Server-side form processing     
      }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`

returns you an Url of type

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/dev`

instead of

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec`,

so the developper version instead of the published version.

The former is subjected to some [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app):

> This URL can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the
> script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved
> code — not necessarily a formal version — and is intended for quick
> testing during development.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045820/dev-vs-exec-documentation-and-mishandling).

### If you change `dev` to `exec` this should solve your issue.

UPDATE:

Either `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`  gives you the `dev` or `exec` URL depends on how you deploy the WebApp.

When you deploy as a new version you have the option to

"Test web app for your latest code":

this will give you the `dev` version.

If you instead run the WebApp by copy-pasting the

`Current web app URL` into your browser:

your `doGet()` function will automatically retrieve the correct `exec` URL with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this before posting this question. Yet I tried it again after reading your answer but it still doesn't solve it.

Comment: Wondering it is browser or the specific URL related, but for me the redirection to "https://stackoverflow.com" works with your code and the `exec` WebApp-Url without issues.

Comment: Thank you, Resolved!!!  
It seems the documentation is not being concrete about the difference in the two versions(dev and exec).  
Again it must be noted that the ids for the two versions are different.  
I am upvoting this answer but I am sticking with the `google.script.run style`.  
Thank you once again.

Comment: The difference about the Ids is certain, sorry for not explaining it properly. I jsut realized that `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` can give you both the correct `dev` and `exec` version - depnding on how you deploy the WebApp. See my updated answer.