# google web app - Update event parameter with html form submit?

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters

I have a web app like this:

file `Code.gs`

```
function doGet(e) 
{
    var id = e.parameter.id;
    if (id == null || id == "")
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("InputId");
    }
    else
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Your id is: "+id);
    }
}
```

File `InputId.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="idEmail">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="idEmail" name="id"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Ok">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the web app works like this:

When user go to: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/SomeYadaYada/dev`

The page shows the form `InputId.html` that asks for user's Id (a.k.a Email), user supposes to enter the Id (e.g YadaYada@gmail.com) then click button Ok.

**Expect:**
The Url bar redirects to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/SomeYadaYada/dev?id=YadaYada@gmail.com` so that the Web app show the text: "Your id is YadaYada@gmail.com".

**Result:**
The Url bar redirects to `https://SomeYadaYada-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?id=YadaYada@gmail.com`, the Web app, of course, shows nothing.

I have googled this whole morning for solution, but I only found [the solution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) "event.preventDefault();" which doesn't work for me (it only prevent the page reload, while I need the page update the event parameter and reload).

How can I update event parameter with html form submit? Or is there a better approach to solve this problem? I hope I can find the solution that will work also when I embed the web app to Google Sites.

Comment: I start to see the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148265/retrieve-url-of-appscript-using-javascript it has something called iFrame: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-published-web-application-sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just need to re-design my app a little bit. Now instead of using form same-page submit to post the event parameter, I just drop the event parameter entirely and using [Google's proposed technique](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

file `Code.gs`

```
function doGet(e) 
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function processForm(formObject) 
{
    var id = formObject.id;

    if (id == null || id == "")
    {
        return "Please enter email.";
    }

    return "Your id is: "+id;
}
```

File `Index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getFormMsg).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function getFormMsg(strMsg) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "<p>"+strMsg+"</p>";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="id" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I like this solution because look like it will work when I embed the web app to Google Sites, save me future headache.

Answer (score 0):

### Implement a link that looks like a button

- Due to [Restrictions in IFRAME mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#restrictions_in_iframe_mode)
   you cannot directly redirect to a new page by opening a new window within the same location, but you can [open a link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#setting_the_link_target_attribute) wihtin the same window.

Sample implementation:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <br>
      <label for="idEmail">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="idEmail" name="id"><br><br>
      <a class="btn btn-primary " id="button">Ok</a>
    </form>     
  </body>
  <script>      
    var button = document.getElementById("button")
    button.addEventListener("click", redirect) 
    function redirect(){
      var baseUrl = "https://script.google.com/a/SomeYadaYada/exec"
      var id = document.getElementById("idEmail").value
      button.href = baseUrl + "?id=" + id
      button.click()
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution because we'll have to edit code at `var baseUrl = "https://script.google.com/a/SomeYadaYada/exec"` each time SomeYadaYada changes, also will it work when embed to Google Sites?

Comment: You do not need to manually change `"https://script.google.com/a/SomeYadaYada/exec"` - it was just a sample. Actually you can retrieve the WebApp Url programmatically with [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#geturl). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544398/htmlservice-xframeoptionsmode-allowall-not-working/62554923#62554923). But if you only want to show an additoinal div rather than redirecting to a completely new website / WebApp of course your solution is totally feasible.