# How to troubleshoot Google login appearing when using Anonymous Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to apps-scripts and want anonymous users to access my web app script that is container bound to a spreadsheet.

The web app displays a form that collects information that the script stores in the containing spreadsheet, it works perfectly when I am logged into my google account, but when logged out the web app url displays a google login screen instead of my form.

I am struggling for the way to troubleshoot this. I have checked:

- the script is deployed to execute as 'me' and with access by anyone + anonymous
- I am using the 'exec' url
- I have put the oauth scopes into the manifest and reduced scope as I can
- I have approved the unverified app.

Here are some extra elements that I don't know whether they are causing issues or not:

- I add a single query parameter to the web app exec url before sending it to the user for them to use anonymously.
- I have a number of other functions in the script apart from the doget(), these process data from the web app form, write data to the containing spreadsheet and return some of it to the user. In the same script I also add a menu to the containing spreadsheet.

There seem very few ways to get logging or troubleshooting information for this problem - especially with container bound scripts. Can anyone with more experience please explain why this problem might occur and suggest how I can troubleshoot and resolve it? As I say the web app url works perfectly when I'm logged in, but when I'm logged out or in incognito mode I get a Google account sign in form.  Thank you.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Rubén thank you. That's a good challenge. I'll come back when I've stripped away the complexity but still have the problem.  It may also be the best way to troubleshoot?

Comment: In my experience usually the real problem arise during the creation of the [mcve], so I think that it's the best way to troubleshoot .

Comment: Is it a Google Login Screen or perhaps a Script Authentication Dialog?

Comment: @Cooper It's a login screen...

Comment: Ok.. so thanks to @Rubén  I'm making progress. The problem I think is caused by V8 returning the dev url from ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(). Through inexperience I thought I could change that by substituting 'exec' for 'dev'. But clearly it doesn't work that way. Can anyone give me more step by step guidance how to return the deployment information, and therefore web app url  using deployments api as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232532/scriptapp-getservice-geturl-points-to-dev-url-how-can-i-get-it-to-point-to) or should I ask it as another question?

Comment: @fireball why can't you hardcode the exec url?

Comment: Yes I've deployed using v8. @TheMaster hardcoding is no problem for my own use but I need to share the script (unverified) with a few other accounts so would like the script to find its own web url. The **Method: projects.deployments.list** workaround appears to give me what I need. I understand the scopes issue... I can get the script id, but I'm not sure how to call it (with authorisation?) from my apps script?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+ScriptApp.getOa*) for authorization samples

Comment: For anyone coming to this in the future Alan Wells has [provided code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986609/find-apps-script-published-url-from-file-url-search-files-by-published-web-app) for how to get deployments information using apps scripting. This doesn't  solve my need however as I'm looking for a way to get the exec web app url that doesn't involve action by the account holder except the usual giving of permission to the script.

Comment: As long as the web app has been deployed then `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` will get the `/exec` url if called from an `/exec` environment, but will get the `/dev` url if called from the `dev` environment. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045820/) for the differences. I don't think you need more than this regardless of version so don't think your auth issue is coming from here. Can you provide your `doGet()` function, list of services you use in your code, and your list of scopes as seen at the `File > Project properties > Scopes` menu item?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232532/scriptapp-getservice-geturl-points-to-dev-url-how-can-i-get-it-to-point-to)?

Comment: @TheMaster I have, but from testing this no longer seems to be the case. Check out [this web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzSDR-1JzGnHWE8A7zbLj4JnY_eKpRcPD6ajvnns9kpLTfvqCxn/exec), the entire code is `function doGet() { return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()); }`. V8 is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this whilst creating a minimal reproducible example as requested.

The problem lay in my confusion over deployments, /exec, /dev and V8 versus rhino.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045820/dev-vs-exec-documentation-and-mishandling) about /dev /exec is very helpful.

What I discovered is:

/dev always asks you to login to your google account if you're not logged in in your browser e.g. incognito mode.

As commented there has been some confusion under what circumstances V8 getUrl() returns /dev or /exec.

My suggestions for troubleshooting this for an anonymous web app:

1. Be very careful when testing anonymous web app using /dev - it will always lead to login request
2. Check very carefully what getURL() is returning - in combination with whether you are using rhino or V8.

I solved my particular problem by 'downgrading' to rhino by putting into the manifest: `"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"`

Comment: I'm glad to know that creating the [mcve] help you. Thanks for sharing your findings.